# How do I convert the geometry of multipolygons to lat and long using r

Tags: r, coordinates, r-sf

Hi I am trying to convert the geometry field into lat and long. I need to use the data to create a map in leaflet for a shiny app.

I have tried the following code:

1. `rl_coord <- rle %>% mutate(lat = unlist(map(rle$geometry, 1)), long = unlist(map(rle$geometry, 2)))`

**output:**
Error in `stopifnot()`:
! Problem while computing `lat = unlist(map(rle$geometry, 1))`.
x `lat` must be size 45152 or 1, not 19470112.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

**sample of data** (first 2 rows):

```
(column names)
oi, name, rle_status, percentage, geometry

1, Aggeneys Gravel Vygieveld, Least Concern, 99, list(c(18.1286933451867, 18.1288873157412, 18.1285209659984, 18.1253701585106, 18.1256087808649, 18.125834301081, 18.1261614439592, 18.1263051557795, 18.1264605244489, 18.1266239843156, 18.1269636452865, 18.12730379009, 18.1274679032905, 18.1276242720226, 18.1277694335806, 18.128129283741, 18.1285605618558, 18.1286933451867, -29.2730674003889, -29.2731573351778, -29.273107503584, -29.273040061747, -29.2729443517532, -29.2728706490378, -29.2727512792674, -29.2727164322246, -29.2726934896327, -29.2726798052816,  -29.2726735519181, -29.2726912387301, -29.2727098853755, -29.2727368207384, -29.272774262715, -29.2728993661673, -29.2730186720589, -29.2730674003889)) 

2,Aggeneys Gravel Vygieveld, Least Concern, 99, list(c(18.1537914281886, 18.1575870517462, 18.1606979380474, 18.1636028297453, 18.1655769358587, 18.16918945379, 18.1735477460181, 18.1759052286574, 18.1772384655054, 18.1773223880217, 18.1776390084706, 18.1759643559649, 18.1735973363743, 18.169952393675, 18.1688938146476, 18.1682070250338, 18.1683513617348, 18.1685030450031, 18.1688311043061, 18.1693585935878, 18.1702652749817, 18.1706158522373, 18.1709379223772, 18.1710792665481, 18.1712000947379, 18.1712925878997, 18.1713437767173, 18.1713693252922,  18.1713707328073, 18.1713479804211, 18.1713015143846, 18.1712382418641, 18.1709475315411, 18.1704635387361, 18.1684209356022, 18.1680682165722, 18.1678999593179, 18.1677395265964, 18.1675893883433, 18.1674634611086, 18.16651344333, 18.1637821201569, 18.1598033908529, 18.1569099426752, 18.1529178620954, 18.14891243025, 18.1454734808983, 18.141641617306, 18.1389141094622, 18.1363582617806, 18.1337413799508, 18.1329259143444, 18.1327123178834, 18.1321225427447, 18.1316307840128, 18.1308981359519, 18.130405823682,  18.1296760299562, 18.1295423948817, 18.1293256727083, 18.1291879582129, 18.1287509532673, 18.1283905796694, 18.1282495214403, 18.1280975604639, 18.1277725515827, 18.1267805933984, 18.1265024871873, 18.1263039910056, 18.1262050407897, 18.1261056638745, 18.1257711483693, 18.1254680798452, 18.1251343803712, 18.1237035930329, 18.1233520704461, 18.1230207288408, 18.1228686758013, 18.122730590917, 18.122428801227, 18.1222578827598, 18.1221962726986, 18.1221588093525, 18.1221453668644, 18.1221553763524,  18.1221897086251, 18.1222487087564, 18.1223573579371, 18.121940612864, 18.119729996386, 18.1201267241008, 18.1202602393336, 18.1232814790033, 18.1262264249677, 18.1309795388961, 18.1359252938222, 18.1414241797188, 18.1456203463775, 18.1505165109378, 18.1537914281886, -29.2714061489315, -29.2729282131844, -29.27283475266, -29.2735366562541, -29.2748603575312, -29.2763805135057, -29.2774333702504, -29.2781257379722, -29.2796611540815, -29.279758428048, -29.2815265405493, -29.282613729886, -29.2822437040154,  -29.2818450674144, -29.2814769494464, -29.2812386697835, -29.2812023081652, -29.2811798583234, -29.2811567953417, -29.2811519774458, -29.2811626612424, -29.2811582844914, -29.2811379726675, -29.2811178709109, -29.2810880943803, -29.2810455977044, -29.2809975064909, -29.2809446550115, -29.2808944231771, -29.2808543392358, -29.2808307426598, -29.2808240597577, -29.2808606799739, -29.2808810489644, -29.2808696770233, -29.2808822434794, -29.280895647919, -29.280916088344, -29.2809458790151, -29.2809806868257,  -29.2806510672722, -29.280271505169, -29.2787456264884, -29.2775611622045, -29.2765159357731, -29.2759494531304, -29.2747535453343, -29.2745113125779, -29.2739715327436, -29.2739181265728, -29.2737464650722, -29.2736922023781, -29.2736427340937, -29.2735310196154, -29.2733754030725, -29.2732322407442, -29.2730770705516, -29.2729311019628, -29.2728915355121, -29.2728078851028, -29.2727640339101, -29.2726519877553, -29.2725284230301, -29.2724913733567, -29.2724634517196, -29.2724256261332, -29.2723486672961,  -29.2723047868547, -29.2722601758286, -29.2722516909261, -29.2722563540645, -29.2723118485858, -29.2723331410326, -29.2723400722685, -29.272324458358, -29.2723303416353, -29.2723548747257, -29.2723790183498, -29.272414889976, -29.2725469760291, -29.2726412327055, -29.2726981781648, -29.2727653543012, -29.2728386599826, -29.2729125214399, -29.2729813861663, -29.2730411602367, -29.2731112309018, -29.2731265774833, -29.2737197621271, -29.2726058704699, -29.272533391812, -29.2709121456387, -29.2701740008779,  -29.2701167811391, -29.2697410330702, -29.2692184199776, -29.2694682832248, -29.2708549256421, -29.2714061489315))
```

Comment: You can use `dput` to share your dataset, it might be much easier (and without errors).

Comment: the class of your rle object is  sf or sp?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sf::st_coordinates` (with reproducible data set). You'll get a list of X and Y coordinates for each multipolygon. You can then use `unnest` to get one row for each X Y pair.

```r
library(spData)
library(sf)
data(nz)

nz %>% 
  transmute(lon = list(st_coordinates(.)[, 1]),
            lat = list(st_coordinates(.)[, 2])) %>% 
  unnest(lon, lat) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry()
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 19,056 × 2
        lon      lat
 *    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 1745493. 6001802.
 2 1740539. 5995066.
 3 1733165. 5989714.
 4 1720197. 5980078.
 5 1709110. 5986672.
 6 1701512. 5996205.
 7 1694072. 5996670.
 8 1698473. 5988332.
 9 1703769. 5984809.
10 1706031. 5975136.
# … with 19,046 more rows
```

---

Or use the wrapper `sfheaders::sf_to_df` (pointed out by @tospig) and select the `x` and `y` columns:

```r
sfheaders::sf_to_df(nz)[c("x", "y")]
```

Comment: `sfheaders::sf_to_df(nz)` will give you a data.frame directly

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
rl_coord <- 
  rle %>%
  sf::st_coordinates() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  select("long" = X, "lat" = Y)

rl_coord
```

Comment: @Maël How is that shorter?  Aside from omitting the `sf::` package qualifier, the only thing you did different was not assign it to a new variable, which might be required by the OP.  Not exactly a shorter yet equivalent method.

Comment: It was edited in the meantime. The original answer was different.